# Can programs interact with other programs programmatically without API or SDK

Tags: windows, programming-languages, hardware

I want to write a python script that interacts with another program; let's call the program Meep and say its a music player. I want to enable the autoplay feature programmatically each time my computer starts; however Meep does not allow autoplay at startup, the user has to select it on Meep's GUI. Is there a way to interact with Meep programmatically; without an API, SDK, or GUI interaction?

Comment: No.  The minimum requirement is an API.  A software development kit is a nice to have.  A GUI allows a person to interact with the software, but for the most part, not other software.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Wouldn't it be possible to mimic user behavior via Win32 API?